# tag synonym request: object-database

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

These tags are synonyms, can someone please mark them?

[object-oriented-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented-database)
[object-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-database)

Thanks!!

Comment: Which one will be the main tag?

Comment: There's also [tag:oodbms]; agree that they're synonyms.

Comment: @rene Wikipedia went with object-database, I recommend going with that one.